# Big Sur 11.6 - After printing is done, the printer no longer auto closes

Tags: big-sur, printing

Title says it for the most part.

[image: My printer after the print job completes]

Prior to 11.6, after I would print, the printer application would automatically close/exit.  Now it no longer does.  I've tried the old trick or right clicking the dock icon and selecting quit but that didn't work this time.  I've looked in Printer preferences and through the printer's menu for options to auto close but have not found anything.

Is there a new way to make the printer auto quit?

---

I have two printers and this does the same for both (and I do get printer specific icons for each printer)

Comment: If you right-click on the icon, under Options, does it say "Remove From Dock"?

Comment: @benwiggy - it's still running, it will say 'Keep in Dock", but I've no clue what that app is, or what printer it's for. Maybe it's a manufacturer-specific issue. I've never known an app pop up in the Dock whilst printing.

Comment: @Tetsujin IME, the print queue app launches when anything is printed.

Comment: Hmm… yup - guess I've never noticed it before. Icon is an image of the specific printer too.

Comment: Same here. Seems to have begun when I updated from 11.5 to 11.6. @benwiggy there is no "Remove From Dock" contextual command. While there is a "Quit" command, the icon returns at the next print job and then, again, remains in the Dock. I'd like the icon to go away when a print job completes.

Comment: @benwiggy Once the print job has completed I have a Keep in dock option but not a Remove from dock option.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - That's exactly what I am seeing and what I'd like.  I'm nearly 100% confident this was broken in the 11.6 update.

Comment: I just gave [Feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) on this issue.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Thanks, I've done the same

Comment: FWIW, I don't see this behaviour in Monterey.

Comment: @benwiggy This behavior is no longer present in macOS Big Sur 11.6.1 too.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidSupportsMonica mentioned in the comments, 11.6.1 fixes this.  I just downloaded the update, printed and my Printer icon is no longer visible in the dock.