# Autoclose printer app on Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, printing

Is there a way or an app that will auto close the printer app on the dock after all print jobs are finished? I've found past solutions online but they seem to stop working for Big Sur.

Comment: This question has been asked [here at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428429/big-sur-11-6-after-printing-is-done-the-printer-no-longer-auto-closes), but has no answer so I cannot mark it as a duplicate.